# Could calls to Writeln() from a thread cause another thread to intermittently miss incoming data from a serial port?

Tags: delphi, serial-port, thread-safety, delphi-xe2

A customer is beta testing a program for me.  He is getting an intermittent error in which the program fails to detect an incoming character from a serial port, which indicates an external device has finished a task.  Try as I may I, cannot repeat the problem in my office, on my computers (many), under test conditions close to what my customer has. My customer has, however, shown me the problem via numerous WebEx sessions.

My program performs a number of tests of sensors, external to the PC. Each test is programmed as a thread.  When each test is performed by selecting a Delphi menu item to run the test, there is no problem.  The thread runs without error.  All characters from the external device are successfully received.

One option, however, is to run all of the tests, automatically, in sequence.  This is where the program misses (intermittently) the incoming character. There is a controller unit which runs each test, in sequence.  That controller is also a thread, and it creates, executes, and destroys each of the sensor test threads, one at a time, in sequence.

One thing that happens differently in the automatic test, however, is that each sensor test thread logs lots of text to a text file.  There is no file I/O when they are run manually.

The file output is done with legacy file I/O, using writeln(f,'sometext'), which is called many, many times. Could this be the problem (non thread safe file I/O)?  My reading on Stackoverflow and elsewhere says yes.

Therefore, I replaced the writeln with this code from an Embarcadero forum:

```
procedure TBaseOperation.WriteLogData(aEventString: String);

//http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/201109/11092512787.html

var
  logFile: TFileStream;
  writer: TStreamWriter;
begin
  try
    logFile := TFileStream.Create('test.txt', fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
  except
    // add code to alert user
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    logFile.Seek(0, soEnd);
    writer := TStreamWriter.Create(logFile);
    try
      writer.WriteLine(aEventString);
    finally
      writer.Free;
    end;
  finally
    logFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Is my thinking in the right direction? Could replacing Writeln with the above code solve the problem?

Writing to a text file is the only thing that the sensor testing threads do differently when they are run automatically.

Comment: File I/O should not be affecting serial port I/O, and vice versa. Unless you are getting your handles mixed up, or using async events that are not being managed correctly, etc.  Without seeing your actual serial port I/O code, I can only guess that it likely has a logic bug that only manifests when doing file I/O, as it is changing the timing of the calling thread, if nothing else. Timing-related bugs are very hard to catch and diagnose. If your serial I/O code were doing everything correctly, it should not be missing any data at all, regardless of what other threads are doing.

Comment: If you can set up a WebEx session with your client, why not also set up remote debugging?  This can seriously save you massive headaches. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overview_of_Remote_Debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the old I/O functions, and especially don't use them in multithreaded applications. They were designed for old single threaded DOS and CP/M applications, and are not thread safe. They are still there for compatibility reasons only, and IMHO it's time they are removed altogether.
Also, threads handling serial communications (or any other task) should avoid to log heavily to a file directly, it's one of the "slower" things you can do in an actual computer, even on a SSD, especially if you open/write/close every time (at least, keep the file open!)
Buffered stream and async I/O could help, but it's far better to have them send log data to another thread which will write data to disk when some threshold is reached.

Answer (score 4):

Without code we can't really offer any specifically useful help.  That said, COM port errors can come from *many* different sources.  Aside from any possible errors in the code, two hardware issues which I've found most likely to cause grief are :

- Buggy RS-232 drivers, especially for USB<->RS-232 adapters, can make these devices utterly unreliable, particularly on newer motherboards with xHCI/USB3.0 chipsets.  If you are using USB-RS-232 devices, disable xHCI in BIOS and see if this corrects the problem.  Devices that use FTDI drivers seem (in my experience) to be the most reliable.  If the device can use an FTDI driver, get the newest ones available, even if the OEM does not provide it (again, especially important on newer motherboards).  Motherboard RS-232 ports and PCI/PCIe USB2.0 cards (which use windows native drivers!) for USB->RS-232 adapters should be used to eliminate other hardware issues in the first instance, ideally.
- Line noise can cause intermittent errors on RS-232 lines.  If you aren't using hardware handshaking and parity bits on your ports, this is doubly a concern, increasingly so in electrically noisy environments (ie: manufacturing or high-energy laboratory environments, etc).  If you're using 115,200kbps with crummy homebuilt cables, expect problems.  If you can test at lower baud rates or use error checking protocols (parity, handshaking) then do so.  I've had systems with decent cables where even 38,400kbps was too fast for the noise environment and caused errors with no-parity/no-handshake protocols.